# How to create a changelog?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audit-trail, changelog

I'm building a site that shows changes in deals that we have in our db. For example, if a deals status changes from pending to win, I want to show it, and if the value goes up or down, I want to show it, that kind of thing. Also, if you open the overview page, I want it to show the history of changes. So I need some kind of change logging, to be able to look in the past. How do I do this?

It is a rails project, but I think that's irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Paper Trail Gem

Since you're on Rails, take a look at the [PaperTrail gem](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail). It does exactly what you're looking for and is beautifully built. You'll just need to add in a callback so that your overview page knows that a change occurred. But for the history of a model, just use the built-in PaperTrail functionality.

Comment: Good to leave this comment, even though late, this is the best answer to the original question, tnx!

Comment: @JasperKennis You bet. Hopefully, it'll save some time for others.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt there is any generic solution to this problem.

You can roll out your own. Start by considering all objects that need change logging. How many types are there? How often do you expect changes to occur? This will help you estimate the potential number of changes throughput you'll need to be dealing with. If there aren't too many, just stick them into database. If you are generating a lot, try storing to comma-separated-value file.

I have implemented a similar system before. I had 3 types of changes: 1) property value change, 2) adding of a value to a list, 3) removing value from a list.

I used the following format, stored in a log file:

```
//For type 1)
1,2011/01/01 00:00:00,MyObject,myProperty,oldValue,newValue
//For type 2)
2,2011/01/01 00:00:00,MyObject,myListProperty,addedValue
//For type 3)
3,2011/01/01 00:00:00,MyObject,myListProperty,removedValue
```

This captured most information I needed. The `value` parts were just some user-readable summary of the changed/added/removed property value.

Comment: That looks good. I've been thinking about something similar, but in json, because it would be very helpful if the log was easy to read with javascript too. Pity their is no standard solution though...

Comment: json sounds good. Not sure about the "general solution" thing. Never heard of one, but there are many clever guys on this website. Someone may have already rolled out one;))